# How do I use fmi2SetReal in C++ to set the value of an input parameter to simulate from an FMU model?

Tags: c++17, fmi

I am trying to use the fmi4cpp API in C++ to run a simulation from a FMU and I would like to set some input parameters. What's the best way to do that for (1) fixed parameters and (2) continuous inputs? I bumped into the fmi2SetReal function but I struggle finding practical examples.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Using fmi4cpp, the call to fmi2SetReal is handled through the `write_real` functions in your slave instance. [Location in source](https://github.com/NTNU-IHB/FMI4cpp/blob/4ebcd8bceb6bb1a60e930f953a6f614f985035d8/include/fmi4cpp/fmu_instance_base.hpp#L215)